# Cannot set recipients - O365

Tags: python, office365api

I'm trying to send e-mail using [O365](https://o365.github.io/python-o365/latest/html/index.html)

However I could not find a way to set the Recipient withouth accessing a private attribute.

```
from O365 import *

my_protocol = MSGraphProtocol(api_version='beta')
account = Account(
    credentials=('id', 'id'),
    protocol=my_protocol
)
if not account.is_authenticated:  # will check if there is a token and has not expired
    # ask for a login
    account.authenticate(scopes=['mailbox', 'message_send'])

msg = Message(parent=account)
msg.body = 'Hi, foobar.'
msg.subject = 'Bar Foo'

msg.to = Recipient(address='foobar@outlook.com', name='lucas') # dont work
msg._Message__to._recipients = [Recipient(address='foobar@outlook.com', name='lucas')] # works but very bad way i supossed
msg.setRecipients(Recipient(address='foobar@outlook.com', name='lucas')) # some old tutorials used this, but dont work either

msg.send()
```

This must be a very stupid question, but I read the classes from the doc and could not find a setter for the recipient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the [github](https://github.com/O365/python-o365).

```
msg.to.add('email')
```

This function add a recipient. Or many if you pass a list of strings.

**Final code**:

```
from O365 import *

my_protocol = MSGraphProtocol(api_version='beta')
account = Account(
    credentials=('id', 'id'),
    protocol=my_protocol
)
if not account.is_authenticated:  # will check if there is a token and has not expired
    # ask for a login
    account.authenticate(scopes=['mailbox', 'message_send'])

msg = Message(parent=account)
msg.body = 'Hi, foobar.'
msg.subject = 'Bar Foo'

msg.to.add('foobar@outlook.com')

msg.send()
```